# I'm getting an error while coding filtering system in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, filtering

**Hello y'all,**

I want to coding filtering in javascript but i have an error (Uncaught TypeError: todos.forEach is not a function) that i don't understand. How can i fix it ?

```js
const todoFilter = document.querySelector('.todoFilter');

todoFilter.addEventListener("click", deneme);

function deneme(e) {
  const todos = todoField.children;
  todos.forEach(element => {
    if (e.target.value = "all") {
      element.style.display = 'flex';
    } else if (e.target.value = "completed") {
      element.style.display = 'flex';

    } else {
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<section class="addField">
  <form>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="options" class="todoFilter">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<section class="todolist">
  <ul class="todos">
    <div class="todo">
      <li>1</li>
      <button class="completeButton">Complete</button>
      <button class="deleteButton">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="todo completed">
      <li>2</li>
      <button class="completeButton">Complete</button>
      <button class="deleteButton">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: When you inspect todos in console, what do you get?

Comment: Well it seems that `todoField` is not defined anywhere, hence you can't loop over its children

Comment: @Reyno Actually i defined it. "const todoField = document.querySelector('.todos');"

Comment: @Grumpy i get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: todos.forEach is not a function.

Comment: Well your code snippet shows otherwise, so please update the snippet.

Comment: `todos` is an `HTMLCollection`, and not a JavaScript array. You can use `Array.from()` method to make an array copy of it and use `forEach` on that. Or use a simple `for` loop to iterate over `HTMLCollection` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) property returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which does not have a `forEach` method.

A solution could be to use a normal for loop:

`for(const child of children) { ... }`

Or convert it to an array first:

`const todos = [...todoField.children]`